# How to reshape a Pivot Table?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I am trying to "reshape" a pivot table:

[image]

I would like to remove those MultiIndex:

[image]

This should be my output:

I have already tried stack, unstack, melt, but I am not getting the result.
At the moment I am saving the Pivot in a CSV, opening the Excel file and deleting manually those extra cells and lines to re-upload on my jupyter (I know it's not a descent job)

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
brincando3 = df4.pivot_table('OCCUPANCY %', 'NAME', 'NEW_TIME', aggfunc='median') \
                .rename_axis(columns=None)
```

1. Don't use `['OCCUPANCY %']` if you don't want an outer level, prefer `'OCCUPANCY %'` if you have only one variable to pivot.
2. `NEW_TIME` is the column label. To remove it, use `rename_axis(columns=None)`.